# haproxy and correct handling of the error message

Tags: string, haproxy, high-availability, health-monitoring, health-check

I have a problem with the proper handling of the application, in general the haproxy configuration looks like this:

```
frontend ui
        bind 192.168.10.40:80
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        option httplog
        use_backend uib

frontend uis
        bind 192.168.10.40:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cloud.pem
        mode http
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        use_backend uib

backend uib
        mode http
        option httpchk OPTIONS /client
        option tcp-check
        tcp-check connect port 9200
        tcp-check expect string is\ synced.
        balance source
                server psc1.piszki.lab:8080 192.168.10.41:8080 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 check
                server psc2.piszki.lab:8080 192.168.10.42:8080 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 check backup
```

This configuration prevents an out-of-sync mariadb node and the absence of an application as such. However, if the application hangs with a DB error (e.g. deadlock), the following message appears:

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /client/
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/client/</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>503</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Service Unavailable</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea how to handle it, I have haproxy 1.8.27, I would be grateful for any suggestions.